# Dynamically allocated memory in structure in c

Tags: c, pointers, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc

I'm trying to create two lists, pros and cons and then print them.
But I can't figure out what am I doing wrong.

I tried to debug the program with gdb online and I found out that the error is in function fgets().

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef struct list{
    char ** reason;

} list;
void printMenu();
void printList(list * myList, int len1);


int main(void)
{
    int keepGoing = 0;
    int choice = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    list * pros;
    list * cons;

    while (!keepGoing){

        printMenu(); 
        scanf("%d", &choice);

        pros = (list*)malloc(sizeof(list));
        cons = (list*)malloc(sizeof(list));
        switch (choice){
        case 1:
            i++;
            printf("Enter a reason to add to list PRO: ");
            pros = (list*)realloc(pros, i*sizeof(list));
            fgets(pros->reason[i], 50, stdin);
            pros->reason[strcspn(pros->reason[i], "\n")] = 0;
            break;
        case 2:
            j++;
            cons = (list*)realloc(cons->reason, j*sizeof(list));
            printf("Enter a reason to add to list CON: ");
            fgets(cons->reason[j], 50, stdin);
            cons->reason[strcspn(cons->reason[j], "\n")] = 0;
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("PROS:\n");
            printList(pros, i);
            printf("CONS:\n");
            printList(cons, j);

            break;
        case 4:
            keepGoing = 1;
            break;
        default:
            printf("Invalid value.");
            keepGoing = 1;
        }
    }

    free(pros);
    free(cons);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}

void printList(list * reasons, int len1){
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < len1; i++){
        printf("%s\n", reasons->reason[i]);
    }
}
void printMenu(){
    printf("Choose option:\n");
    printf("1 - Add PRO reason\n");
    printf("2 - Add CON reason\n");
    printf("3 - Print reasons\n");
    printf("4 - Exit\n");
}
```

Comment: what is `count`?

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: Well you `malloc` each loop the struct ... therefore erase the data each loop. Also you use `realloc` on something that never been allocate before [even if `realloc` will allocate the size, you should use `malloc`]. Alos `keepGoing` is always equals to 1; you've got an endless loop; and then you will never free it [you forget to free the list]

Comment: `while (!keepGoing)`? Really? How do you read that? The only way I know is "while not keep going (: keep going)". That makes no sense at all.

Comment: There are many issues, your `struct list` declaration is fishy and your program is overly complicated. Maybe you should show us the expected behaviour of your program.

Comment: Ok. I wan't to create a program which will be taking from the user each time(until he wants to exit) pro reason and con reason and then print him all reasons. And I have to use the function malloc().

Comment: @MichaelWalz ^^^^

Comment: @Saga you should put that into your question by editing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many issues. Previous comments and answers do still apply.

Here is a clean solution.

- The list structure is now self contained, no need to track the number of strings in separate variables
- added selfcontained `AddString` function
- no more unnecessary `malloc`s
- all allocated memory is freed correctly
- some logic errors removed (inverted logic of `keepGoing`)

There is still room for improvement. Especially there is no error checking for the memory allocation functions.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct list {
  int size;       // number of strings
  int chunksize;  // current of chunk
  char ** reason;
} list;

void printMenu();
void printList(list * reasons);
void freeList(list * l);
void AddString(list *l, const char *string);

int main(void)
{
  int keepGoing = 1;
  int choice = 0;

  list pros = { 0 };  // = {0} initializes all fields to 0
  list cons = { 0 };

  while (keepGoing) {

    printMenu();
    scanf("%d", &choice);

    char input[50];
    fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);  // absorb \n from scanf

    switch (choice) {
    case 1:
      printf("Enter a reason to add to list PRO: ");
      fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);
      AddString(&pros, input);    // Add string to pros
      break;
    case 2:
      printf("Enter a reason to add to list CONS: ");
      fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);
      AddString(&cons, input);    // Add string to cons
      break;
    case 3:
      printf("PROS:\n");
      printList(&pros);
      printf("CONS:\n");
      printList(&cons);
      break;
    case 4:
      keepGoing = 0;
      break;
    default:
      printf("Invalid value.");
      keepGoing = 1;
    }
  }

  freeList(&pros);
  freeList(&cons);

  getchar();
  return 0;
}


#define CHUNKSIZE 10

void AddString(list *l, const char *string)
{
  if (l->size == l->chunksize)
  {
    // resize the reason pointer every CHUNKSIZE entries
    l->chunksize = (l->chunksize + CHUNKSIZE);

    // Initially l->reason is NULL and it's OK to realloc a NULL pointer
    l->reason = realloc(l->reason, sizeof(char**) * l->chunksize);
  }

  // allocate memory for string (+1 for NUL terminator)
  l->reason[l->size] = malloc(strlen(string) + 1);

  // copy the string to newly allocated memory
  strcpy(l->reason[l->size], string);

  // increase number of strings
  l->size++;
}

void freeList(list * l) {
  for (int i = 0; i < l->size; i++) {
    // free string
    free(l->reason[i]);
  }

  // free the list of pointers
  free(l->reason);
}

void printList(list * l) {
  for (int i = 0; i < l->size; i++) {
    printf("%s\n", l->reason[i]);
  }
}

void printMenu() {
  printf("Choose option:\n");
  printf("1 - Add PRO reason\n");
  printf("2 - Add CON reason\n");
  printf("3 - Print reasons\n");
  printf("4 - Exit\n");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to allocate these dynamically: `list * pros; list * cons;`. Code like `pros = (list*)realloc(pros, i*sizeof(list));` doesn't make any sense.

Instead, declare them as plain variables. `list pros`.

What you instead need to allocate dynamically is the member `pros.reason`. You need to allocate an array of pointers that it points to, and then you need to allocate the individual arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem in

```
  fgets(pros->reason[i], 50, stdin);
```

as the memory you want to *use* is not *valid*. `pros->reason` does not point to a valid memory, so you cannot dereference it, this causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Before you can index-into `pros->reason`, you need to make `pros->reason` point to a valid memory location.

After that, you need to make `pros->reason[i]`s also to point to valid memory if you want them to be used as the *destination* of `fgets()`.

---

Apart from this issue, you have another issue which makes this code nonsense, that is calling `malloc()` on every iteration of the loop. You need to call `malloc()` only once, to get a pointer (to memory) allocated by memory allocator function and then, use `realloc()` inside the loop to *adjust* that to the required memory.

Comment: There is lot more problem then that :x (alloc list at each loop, realloc something that should be alloc first ( even if realloc will create the memory))

Comment: You mean something like this?

pros->reason = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*SIZE);

Comment: @Saga something along that line, yes.

Comment: I tried to do it, however there's a new error exactly in this line of code.
"Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault."

Comment: @Saga yes, probably because `pros->reason[i]` is still pointing to invalid memory, check the last part of my answer.

Comment: First I have to allocate memory for pros->reason[i] and then to pros->reason?

Comment: @Saga nopes, the other way.

Comment: First allocate memory pros->reason and then to pros->reason[i]. I started doing it and it stopped in this line:  
pros->reason =(char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*SIZE);
Can you please write only where to write the 2 lines? As I understood, I should write this line of code outside the while loop and inside the while loop allocate memory for pros->reason[i]

Comment: @SouravGhosh ^^

Comment: @Saga OK, i'll do, gimme some time please.